# matrix operator norm and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Is it true that $\Vert A\Vert:=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert Ax\Vert=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=\Vert y\Vert=1}\vert\langle y,Ax\rangle\vert$ for arbitrary matrices $A$?
Showing $"\geq"$ seems to be straightforward using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Have a look at the first part of my proof here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158881/h%C3%B6lders-inequality-for-matrices/197868#197868

Comment: From Surb's linked answer: this is true, and we can generalize this result to state that
$$
\|A\|_p = \max_{x,y\neq 0} \frac{\langle y,Ax\rangle}{\|y\|_{p'}\|x\|_p} 
$$
Where $\|A\|_p$ denotes the induced $p$-norm, and $1/p + 1/p' = 1$.

Comment: A much more general case is proved in this paper:http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01273v1.pdf (see Proposition 5). The result there implies that for every $A\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ we have
$$\max_{x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}} \frac{\| Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_q}=\max_{x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\},y\in \Bbb R^m\setminus\{0\}} \frac{\langle x,Ay\rangle}{\|y\|_{p'}\|x\|_{q}}$$
For any $1<p,q<\infty$ and where $p'=p/(p-1)$.

Answer (score 9):

The other direction is also short but I will provide all details. Notice that letting $y = \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$ in your expression and taking the supremum over all $x$ gives
$$
\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \left|\left\langle \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}, Ax\right\rangle\right| \leq \sup_{\|x\| = \|y\| = 1} |\langle y, Ax\rangle|
$$
by definition of a supremum because the set on which we take the supremum on the left hand side is $\left\{(x, y) : \|x\| = 1, y = \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}\right\}$ which is a subset of the set on which we take the supremum on the right hand side which is $\{(x, y): \|x\| = \|y\| = 1\}$.

Now simplifying the left hand side gives
$$
\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \left|\left\langle \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}, Ax\right\rangle\right| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \frac{1}{\|Ax\|} |\langle Ax, Ax\rangle| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \frac{1}{\|Ax\|} \|Ax\|^2 = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \|A\|
$$
which finishes the proof after using it in the above inequality.

Note that this works for all bounded operators on any normed vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $z$ is such that $\|Az\| = \|A\|$.  Then
$$
\sup_{\|x\|=1,\|y\|=1} |\langle x,Ay \rangle| \geq 
\left|\langle Az/\|A\|,Az \rangle \right| = 
\frac 1{\|A\|}
\left|\langle Az,Az \rangle \right| = \|A\|
$$
This works in the finite dimensional case where the sup is really a max.  In the infinite dimensional case, it still suffices to choose $z$ such that $\|Az\| \geq \|A\| - \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: .... well this proof works only when $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.. It is not true in general that $|\langle Az,Az\rangle | = \|Az\|^2$ (actually this is very rare)

Comment: @Surb: You mean, this proof on an inner product space only works when $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm induced by that inner product?

Comment: this proof, yes! but as I commented in the OP you can make it for $p$ norms and even for $p,q$ norms of matrices

Comment: Anyway, +1 for treating the infinite dimensional case. Moreover, looking at the expression in OP, apparently the norm used is self-dual so that your proof is suited for the problem.